# Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a web app with laravel. 
**First Question:**
There's a simple form on users dashboard to fill and save.
Here's the model:

```
class Salon extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'salons';
    protected $fillable = [
        'salonname', 'saloncity', 'salonaddress', 'salontel', 'salonmob', 'salonsite', 'saloncat', 'salonkhadamat', 'salonkhadamatprice', 'salondesc', 'saloninsta', 'salontelegram', 'salontags'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

and here is the controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    Salon::create([
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'salonname' => $request['salonname'],
        'saloncity' => $request['saloncity'],
        'salonaddress' => $request['salonaddress'],
        'salontel' => $request['salontel'],
        'salonmob' => $request['salonmob'],
        'salonsite' => $request['salonsite'],
        'saloncat' => $request['saloncat'],
        'salonkhadamat' => $request['salonkhadamat'],
        'salonkhadamatprice' => $request['salonkhadamatprice'],
        'salondesc' => $request['salondesc'],
        'saloninsta' => $request['saloninsta'],
        'salontelegram' => $request['salontelegram'],
        'salontags' => $request['salontags']
    ]);

    return 'done!';
}
```

And the routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/salons/add', function () {
    return view('add_salon');
})->middleware('auth');
Route::post('salons', 'SalonsController@store');
Route::get('salons', function () {
    return 'Hi';
});
```

When I complete the form and hit send button, it returns this error :

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `salons` (`salonname`,...

Where am I doing wrong? 
I created a table migration as :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('Salons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('salonname');
        $table->string('saloncity');
        $table->string('salonaddress');
        $table->integer('salontel');
        $table->integer('salonmob');
        $table->string('salonsite');
        $table->string('saloncat');
        $table->string('salonkhadamat');
        $table->integer('salonkhadamatprice');
        $table->string('salondesc');
        $table->string('saloninsta');
        $table->string('salontelegram');
        $table->string('salontags');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

user_id is using a foreign reference from users table.
let me explain the process, consider we have some users registered on our app, some of them want to add their salons on our website, so we want to use the user_id from the users table on salons table, so we can return salons with the user's data (profile) on our homepage.
**Second question:**
If a salon have two separate telephone numbers, How can I store them in this table separately? 
I mean, people can add many telephone-numbers as they want. Or as many addresses as they have, in separate fields.

**Third question:**
For creating a portfolio section for each salon, Should I create a new table such as attachments to have pictures addresses and salon id to return them on their respective page later?

Comment: for your second question, you should make a new table with telephone numbers with a has many relation to saloon table. For your third question, yes you should make a new one with has many relation with saloon table by saloon id

Comment: Thanks @Sohel0415

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `user_id` to the fillable array too:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'salonname', 'saloncity', 'salonaddress', 'salontel', 'salonmob', 'salonsite', 'saloncat', 'salonkhadamat', 'salonkhadamatprice', 'salondesc', 'saloninsta', 'salontelegram', 'salontags'];
```

Or use the relationship if it is defined:

```
$salon = auth()->user()->salons()->create([....
```

If it's not defined:

```
public function salons()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Salon::class);
}
```

Comment: Is it safe ? so users can edit the user_id and change other salons data on the database.

Comment: @M.Safari if you control it, it's safe. But the better approach is to use relationship.